# How to count a field per day and then GROUP BY YEARWEEK

Tags: mysql, date, count, sum

If i have a database with 2 columns, date and account and i want to first count account per day and then group by week. How wrong is my code and how to do it?
I edited my code a little bit, i was not thinking right from the beginning. I want the sum to be 9 for week 48.

```
SELECT date, account,
(SELECT date, COUNT(DISTINCT account) 
FROM t1 
GROUP BY date
) AS sum

FROM t1
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a simple aggregate query with `count(distinct ...)`:

```
select yearweek(date) year_week, count(distinct account) cnt_account
from t1
group by yearweek(date)
order by year_week
```

Note: `yearweek()` gives you the year *and* week; this is better than `week()`, if your data spreads over several years.

**EDIT**

From the comments, you need two levels of aggregation:

```
select yearweek(dy) year_week, sum(cnt) cnt_account
from (
    select date(t1.date) dy, count(distinct t1.account) cnt
    from t1
    group by date(t1.date)
) t
group by yearweek(dy)
order by year_week
```

Comment: This code gives me a value of 3 because it counts distinct per week. I want it to count distinct per day and then summarize it in weeks. So the value should be 9.